# Change colour of ckeditor show blocks border

Tags: ckeditor

The ckeditor editor window for the site content areas has a blue background to match the website so that the client sees a true representation of the website while adding content.

When "show blocks" is selected the blocks border displayed is barely visible on the blue background.
Therefore, where can the colour of the show blocks border be changed to a darker colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, color of border displayed for blocks isn't customizable. CSS that styles them is generated by JS. You can find it here http://dev.ckeditor.com/browser/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/showblocks/plugin.js#L28

I guess that you're using compiled version of CKEditor, so source is minified. You'll have to open `ckeditor.js` file and find this fragment and change it manually.

Or you can try to clone CKEditor 4 (new version that will be release next Tuesday), change this value here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/showblocks/plugin.js#L48 and then compile your build of CKEditor (you can find instructions here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev). But to do this you'd need Mac or Linux, because build script is written in Bash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Took some time but found the fragment in ckeditor.js for the borders and successfully changed to black.
The text at the top left for each block is shown by png images and the text is grey so will have to change text colour to black in all the png files

Comment: This all works well now. Both the black show blocks border and the black html tags in the new png images show up well on the blue background.

Answer (score 0):

CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    uiColor: '#14B8C4'
});

Update :-

Check the sample url:[ckeditor](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/3983/samples/uicolor.html)